# Frequency analysis

Tags: statistics, frequency, analysis

Suppose I have an experimental and control group and have 2 categories (attractive, less attractive) that their frequency is noted, what type of statistical tool should I use?

Experimental group Attractive category = 35, Less attractive category = 15
Control group Attractive category = 25, Less attractive category = 25

Answer (score 0):

Try with fishers exact test, assuming case and control are independent.